# Black screen when app is opened before calling Ti.App.iOS.endBackgroundHandler(e.handlerId);

Tags: ios, objective-c, titanium

I have a simple test app for iOS in titanium which has the capability to respond to silent push notifications.

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({

});
var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
   borderRadius:10,
   backgroundColor:'red',
   width:50,
   height:50
});
Ti.App.iOS.addEventListener("silentpush", function (e) {
    if (e && typeof e !== 'undefined' && e.aps && e.aps['content-available'] && typeof     e.aps['content-available'] !== 'undefined') {
        Ti.API.info('silent push received in app.js');
    }
});

window.add(view);
window.open();
```

If a silent push is received and I open the app, I get a black screen. If I press the home button again and reopen the app, the black screen vanishes.

Also if I call `Ti.App.iOS.endBackgroundHandler(e.handlerId);` inside the event listener, the black screen doesn't appear. But I guess `Ti.App.iOS.endBackgroundHandler(e.handlerId);` should be called only when the processing is complete.

Generally if the app is opened before the 30 second window provided by apple for background download or before `Ti.App.iOS.endBackgroundHandler(e.handlerId);` is called, I get a black screen.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't set a background for your window.  Looks like it defaults to black.  I'd expect to see a black window with a red box in the middle of it.  Perhaps it is because you are using window, which is a JavaScript reserved word.  Your syntax highlighting should show you that difference between var view and var window.  Use a different variable name for window.

Comment: Tried changing the  variable window to a different name, same result.

Comment: I commented out that listener code.  Works for me on my sim.

Comment: Silent push notifications cannot be tested on the simulator. The problem occurs when a silent push notification is received and we open the app immediately after that.

Comment: Titanium has acknowledged this issue, https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-4703